# Application Relative Paths IIS

Tags: iis, iis-7, iis-6

I'm moving an web application to a subdirectory from it's root and having issues with paths.

Old: `http://www.domain.com/`

New: `http://www.domain.com/app/`

All of the include css, scripts and html links where in this format:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles/menu.css" media="screen"/>
```

I've changed to:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./styles/menu.css" media="screen"/>
```

or

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/styles/menu.css" media="screen"/>
```

It works fine on links and others until I go one directory deep where links and paths are broken.

e.g.

```
www.domain.com/app/dir1/
www.domain.com/app/dir2/
```

There the link url or others (scripts, includes, etc) get duplicate paths.

e.g.

```
www.domain.com/app/dir1/dir1/
www.domain.com/app/dir2/dir2/
```

How could I approach this as absolute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using ~/style... etc is the easiest solution in ASP.NET but you must put runat="server" in the tag for it to actually work